Syntactic problems with Redux middleware when try to add .concat(authMiddleware)
Here is authMiddleware:
"use client";
import { Middleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { clearUserProfile } from "../reducers/userProfile";
import { clearIdToken } from "../reducers/auth";
import { RootState } from "..";

const authMiddleware: Middleware<{}, RootState> = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    const state = store.getState();
    const { auth } = state;
    const currentTime = Date.now();

    if ((auth.token_expiry && auth.token_expiry < currentTime) || auth.token_expiry === null) {
        store.dispatch(clearIdToken());
        store.dispatch(clearUserProfile());
        window.location.href = "/authentication/login";
    }

    return next(action);
};

export default authMiddleware;

When I try to add .concat(authMiddleware) below but "middleware" is underscore redline:
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        persistedReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        }).concat(authMiddleware),
});

The issue is:

The expected type comes from property 'middleware' which is declared here on type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<{ persistedReducer: PersistPartial; }, UnknownAction, Tuple<Middlewares<{ persistedReducer: PersistPartial; }>>, Tuple<...>, { ...; }>'

How do I fix it or use another idea to add middleware?
